# Is it possible to constrain arguments NOT to be delegates?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Consider these two functions:

```
'Overload 1
<Extension()>
Function ComputeReturnValue(Of TSource, TResult)(ByVal source As TSource, ByVal IfTrueFunc As 
System.Func(Of TSource, TResult), ByVal IfFalseFunc As System.Func(Of TSource, TResult)) As TResult

    Return If([some test is true], IfTrueFunc(source), IfFalseFunc(source))
End Function

'Overload 2
<Extension()>
Function ComputeReturnValue(Of TSource, TResult)(ByVal source As TSource, ByVal IfTrueValue As 
TResult, ByVal IfFalseFunc As TResult) As TResult

    Return If([some test is true], IfTrueValue, IfFalseValue)
End Function
```

In words, `ComputeReturnValue` performs some test (not important right now) and returns different values depending on the result.  I have two versions, because sometimes I want to return the result of calling a function to form the result, and sometimes I just want to return fixed values.

The problem is that when I (try to) call overload 1, instead of invoking the right function, the compiler calls *overload 2*, and returns the `Func(Of TSource, TResult)` object and not the result of *calling* the function.  I see that this is because overload 2 doesn't constrain the types, and so a Func is a valid argument for this routine, and I'm willing to believe that the compiler is choosing the overload correctly in this case.

My question is: what is the right way to accomplish this to resolve the ambiguity so that I can pass value or references types and get overload 2, but pass Functions and get overload 1?  Can I constrain the types in some way to make this happen?  Or should I just name them different names and avoid the problem?

(I know I could just keep the Func version, and pass in a trivial `Function() IfTrueValue` for when I want to return a value, but I'm trying to make this as syntactic sugary as possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely give them different names. Whenever you fight against overload resolution, think of whoever's coming after you - and is likely to be *less* familiar with the code. Anything that's tricky for you will be even trickier for them, whereas giving the methods different, descriptive names will make everyone's life better.

Comment: I am sure you're right.  I will give them different names.  Thanks.